# Python 3.10 warning

Tags: python, pycharm, warnings

```
warning: PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON environment variable is set to 'NO'. Frame evaluator will be also disabled because it requires Cython extensions to be enabled in order to operate correctly.
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py:1844: DeprecationWarning: currentThread() is deprecated, use current_thread() instead
  dummy_thread = threading.currentThread()
```

I installed the newest version of python, deleted older one and this warning poped up. Python codes run as usual, but this message pops up after debugging. I use Pycharm as an IDE. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Scrolling to the bottom here, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugger-python.html, it appears `cython` speedups are not available above `3.8` yet. This emits the warning here https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/f0cecf7cb53547b475709be750113bfcce516aa3/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_frame_eval/pydevd_frame_eval_main.py#L23

Comment: That means I should install older version again?

Comment: If you don't want to see the warning. If you're ok with the warning, there shouldn't be any harm in using it.

Comment: That warning won't interrupt codes I run?

Comment: It shouldn't. It's just warning you about potential slowdowns and `threading.currentThread()` which will be removed in a future python version.

Comment: @DavidKhutsishvili Would you please have a look at my answer below and mark it as correct if it resolved your question?

Answer (score 12):

This was fixed in Pycharm 2021.3. Upgrade and it will go away.

See [2021.3 release notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/PyCharm+2021.3+Release+Notes?utm_source=product&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=TBA).

```
Bug     PY-44838    Build debugger binaries for Python 3.10
```

Comment: This is the correct answer now that PyCharm 2021.3 is available

Comment: I have `Build #PY-231.8109.197, built on March 29, 2023`, still got that error

Answer (score 3):

I have the same notification after moving to python 3.10

The thing is disabled Cython speedups for Python 3.10 intentionally as they are breaking the debugger.
JetBrains  are working on the fix and will bundle the pre-compiled speedups for Python 3.10 on Windows (as they do for other versions)

[Link to issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44838)