# Pycharm debugger(version 2022.2.3) stops with DeprecationWarning

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I know it was noted here: [Python 3.10 warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69728163/python-3-10-warning)
but... I am using Pycharm version 2022.2.3 (most recent) and `still` cannot run debugger. I still get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    output_checker_thread = self.output_checker_thread = CheckOutputThread(self)
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/302/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.setName('pydevd.CheckAliveThread')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1246, in setName
    warnings.warn('setName() is deprecated, set the name attribute instead',
DeprecationWarning: setName() is deprecated, set the name attribute instead
```

I work on Ubuntu 22.04. Pycharm is 2022.2.3 (community edition). It's been a month since I moved to Python 3.10 and I can't use my IDE debugger! maybe I should manually change `how` the debugger is run? Like turn off warnings, maybe? I can't find where and how I can do it though...

Answer (score 1):

I created a ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker for this problem https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-56773/helperspydevpydevdpy166-DeprecationWarning-setName-is-deprecated

A dirty quick workaround is to edit `/snap/pycharm-community/302/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py` line 166 converting

```
self.setName('pydevd.CheckAliveThread')
```

to

```
self.name = 'pydevd.CheckAliveThread'
```

Comment: Thanks for a prompt response and creating a ticket! I will postpone this change till later because I'll need to remount the read-only file system, right? I am running tests manually,  without the debugger, that's good enough for now. I may even wait for the next release with fixes (hopefully)

Comment: @LeoSkhrnkv I've pushed the fix. It will be available in the 2022.3 release (starting with EAP 4).

Comment: Thanks! I can't wait for it